# LOCK TABLES inside TRANSACTION does not ROLLBACK

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a problem and it is that I need to lock tables within a transaction to prevent data from being inserted into it, but when I do this when I have an error the transaction rollback does not work.

I read in mysql articles that table locks break a transaction, but is there any other way to lock tables to prevent data from being inserted into it temporarily?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html

```
try {
     DB::beginTransaction();

     DB::unprepared('LOCK TABLES table_name WRITE');
     //
     DB::unprepared('UNLOCK TABLES');

     DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $e){
     DB::rollBack();
}
```

Comment: What is the error? But more importantly what is the"prevent data from being inserted" criteria? Is it really the entire table? What is the high level requirement about your inserts? What is the table structure `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`? `LOCK TABLES` should be rarely needed in transaction sql programming.

Comment: Did you fix the issue?

Answer (score -1):

You can lock the tables in the outer scope, outside of the transaction.

Then, your example code would look like:

```php
try
{
    DB::unprepared('LOCK TABLES table_name WRITE');

    try
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        
        //...

        DB::commit();
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        DB::rollBack();
    }
}
finally
{
    DB::unprepared('UNLOCK TABLES');
}
```